# URL that changes on timer attached to an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do is have an URL that changes on a timer that is attached to an image. So let's say, after 10 seconds, the URL changes (not the image) I want the image not to change, Instead, just the link URL attached to it.

I was thinking that there was someway to modify this code. But I haven't the faintest clue in what way.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/></a>
```

I was thinking something like this?

```
<script>
var urlArray = [
"URL 1",
"URL 2",
"URL 3"
];

setTimeout(function() {
}, 60000);
}

</script>
```

Only problem I don't know how to incorporate the image url or if this would even work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what links are you wanting to loop through?

Comment: My website links. I updated my answer. @NewToJS

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks so much. If you post it as in answer, I'll be more than happy to mark it as the correct answer. Thank you so much. @NewToJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

I have added comments into the source code and the interval (not timeout) is set to 5 seconds `5000` for demo purposes. If you want this to run every 10 seconds just change the interval to `10000`

```js
var urls=[
'http://www.google.com',
'http://www.youtube.com',
'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
];
var x=0;

window.onload=function(){
setInterval(function(){ // Interval
x++; // Use to increment array
if(x>urls.length-1){x=0} // End of Array? Reset x
// Target anchor tag by ID.        Next Item In Array
document.getElementById('MyUrls').href=urls[x];
}, 5000);
}
```

```html
<a id="MyUrls" href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/>
</a>
```

And here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyfhk410/)

If you have ant questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as  soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!